# Orders of ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ for different $(n,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Every undergraduate or beginner-graduate knows that the family [projective linear groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group)  ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ over finite field of order $q=p^k$ is a family of simple groups (with $(n,q)\neq (2,2)$ and $(n,q)\neq (2,3)$).

It is easy to compute orders of these groups, and these groups are "different" (non-isomorphic) from $A_n$, with finitely many exceptions.

The problems I will consider here is about the orders of these groups;

> for $(n,q)\neq (n_1,q_1)$ does the groups ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ and ${\rm PSL}(n_1,q_1)$ have *different orders* with finitely many exceptions? Proof?

Note that for different values of $(n,q)$, it is easy to prove that the corresponding groups are **non-isomorphic** (with one or two exceptions), whereas I am considering here **only orders** of them.

---

After comments by many: some modification is done in question.

Comment: I think this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107620/non-isomorphic-finite-simple-groups will probably answer all your questions.

Comment: @Donkey: Thanks for the reference. The link answers that in lower dimensions, some equality of orders holds. But, what about other orders? Are they all distinct orders?

Comment: The link asserts that the examples given in lower dimensions are the only examples of nonisomorphic finite simple groups of the same order.

Comment: Since the groups $PSL(n,q)$ considered here are finite simple groups, this Question is a subset of the broader one, [For which numbers there is only one simple group of that order?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153324/for-which-numbers-there-is-only-one-simple-group-of-that-order).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\text{PSL}(3,4)$ and $\text{PSL}(4,2)\cong A_8$, though non-isomorphic, both have order $20160$.  This is the only example if we disregard the isomorphisms $\text{PSL}(2,4)\cong\text{PSL}(2,5)$ and $\text{PSL}(2,7)\cong\text{PSL}(3,2)$

Quoting from https://mathoverflow.net/a/107660/70015:

> the only nonisomorphic finite simple groups with the same orders are
>
> 1. $A_8 \cong {\rm PSL}(4,2)$ and ${\rm PSL}(3,4)$ of order 20160.
> 2. The groups ${\rm P \Omega}_{2n+1}(q)$ and ${\rm PSp}_{2n}(q)$ for all odd prime powers $q$ and $n \ge 3$. These have order
>
> $$(q^{n^2} \Pi_{i=1}^n (q^{2i}-1))/2$$

Since $\text{PSL}(n,q)$ is a finite simple group for all $n,p$

Comment: I mentioned it **...with one or two exceptions**.

Comment: @Groups OK...is the second example I just added any better?

Comment: I don't understand what "no" means here.  The Question asks when the groups $PSL(n,q)$ have different orders.

Comment: that's OK. I would also like to see whether these are **exceptional cases**.

Comment: @hardmath The question in yellow in the OP is a yes-or-no question, which I interpret to mean, "Does $(n, q) \neq (n', q')$ imply that $\#PSL(n, q) \neq \#PSL(n', q')$?" I have to say, I don't quite understand OP's statement after this question, however.

Comment: @Donkey, hardmath, Travis: to avoid wrong confusions, shall I slightly modify question? Donkey, you may keep your answer as it is.

Comment: Yes please.$\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry for inconvenience.