# For any $n$, there are at most two simple groups of order $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How do you prove that for any $n$ there are at most two simple groups of order $n$?

Comment: Homework?  Exam?  What have you tried?

Comment: very interesting question... It would have been better if you could have specified what you have done....

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/number-of-finite-simple-groups-of-given-order-is-at-most-2-is-a-classification asks for a proof of this fact that doesn't use the classification of finite simple groups.

Comment: @JohnEngbers Your question implicitly says this is easy or routine. I'd be interested in seeing a homework-level easy/routine argument. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this very particular case, I see no advantage in asking "what have you done".

Comment: I agree that this (seems to be) a difficult question; on a question such as this I find it useful to know some context behind the posing of the question.  For example, is this useful in a sdfsadf's research?  Is it for a lecture in a group theory course?  Eliciting further information related to the question was the reason I commented above.

Answer (score 5):

You use the classification of finite simple groups. There is no a priori reason.

Comment: ... that we (or you?) know of...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What else could I mean? (to help the slow children among us: "the only proof of that fact I am aware of uses classification"). And thanks for the downvote.

Comment: "The only proof of that fact I am aware of uses classification" has a wide variety of meanings, since readers don't know the depth of your knowledge. Are you a person with deep knowledge about group theory? Etc. That's why the answer is less than useful - there is no way to tell the reliability of the claim.  I suspect, from reading the answer to the related question, that you are correct, but there is not any context in your answer.

Comment: I agree with Igor's answer: the OP is not asking for an *elementary* proof (alas, the OP is just *spitting* the question).

Comment: If I were to write "The only proof of that fact I am aware of uses classification..." that would have a different meaning than if Walter Feit wrote it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are free to Google my name and determine whether you find the information supplied trustworthy. Of course, you are also free to be a jerk, and I am glad that you are taking advantage of your freedoms. As for Walter Feit, had he posted an answer we would have deeper problems than the OPs.

Comment: But if one has to google the answerer to gauge the value of the answerer, that makes the answer not useful in the long run. I was not questioning your credentials, I was saying your answer is only useful if we know your credentials, and that makes the answer incomplete.

Comment: As a wiser man than I had noted, in the long run we are all dead (some of us, like Professor Feit, are, unfortunately, dead in the short run, too).

Comment: So why bother answering questions at all? That's just nihilistic nonsense. If an answer's meaning depends on the level of the answerer's expertise (such as practically any "not that I know of" answer) the answer is inherently incomplete without some details of who you are.

Comment: "You use the CFSG. There is no a priori reason"....this doesn't answer at all, or perhaps it does, the OP's question: does this mean "yes, it's true and for that use the CFSG, though there is no a priori reason"( and one could even argue here: there's no a priori reason a differentiable function has to be continuous, either: one *proves* that), or perhaps it means "use the CSFG, hopefully the answer is there. I've no the faintest idea, but there's no a priori reason" . About the downvoting: I don't like that under almost any circumstances.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What exactly is your point? I am not user123445, I publish my name, so anybody is free to assess my level of expertise as much as they like.

Comment: And thanks to @julien for the edit which puts an end to this ridiculous discussion.

Comment: That means that the answer is not self-contained. That's all I'm saying. The point is to give self-contained answers. See the answer to the duplicate question above. The goal of this site is to give self-contained questions and answers. Even if you included a link to your CV, I'd have complained, because the answer itself would not be complete.

Comment: Come on guys, please stop this polemic discussion here, or do it outside this medium.

Comment: @NickyHekster I think it was over by the time you commented.